# Best practice for storing external text to then place in html

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, internationalization

Sorry if I'm not explaining the question well in the title, I'm not sure of the correct lingo. Let me give you an example instead.

So this is a normal HTML file.

```
<span>Welcome to the site!</span>
```

I would like to make it a bit more dynamic by perhaps having in the JS.

```
<script>
$scope.welcome = "Welcome to the site!";
</script>
```

In the HTML

```
<span>{{welcome}}</span>
```

Now I have just had a large JSON array in a separate JS file and loaded it in to the `<head>` and then called it.

Is this the correct way or is there a proper practice? The closest thing I can think of is `Internationalization` in Java.

Comment: I have a project that I made 100% internationalized my approach was similiar to yours. I put a meta tag as a key value storage in html. ex: `<meta content="Your JSON" data-id = 'my-key-to-access-this' />`  I see this approach in airbnb view-source:https://www.airbnb.com/  if you check the footer in airbnb they used the meta tags as a key value storage. So You could use for it.

Comment: I see but what's the benefit to loading it in a meta tag instead of just as another JS file?

Comment: There is no problem if you use good http validation, but if you don't use correct headers, and if there is no http2 or spdy, it may make an overhead like extra socket connections etc.

Comment: As a second concern, the first one may not be a problem if you are using js, css merging and minifying. But you may not want to add all application translations to the one file. You may desire to load related page translations then it would be better to load your translations etc. dynamically. Then this approach would make more sense and if you don't want to get the json from DOM, you could also place it in a variable which is placed between `<script></script>` tags

Comment: You can load external text in your server/client. This may be relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49439995/how-can-i-get-an-array-of-json-object-from-a-webpage-and-add-each-element-to-the

Answer (score 2):

If you have no additional requirements besides what you mentioned in your question, **this is perfectly fine**. See KISS and YAGNI.

You should only consider doing something more complicated right now if you *know* you're going to need something like internationalization, since deciding on a satisfactory getCorrectStringForCurrentLanguage() mechanism and porting all your existing string code to it will be much harder if you put it off until later. And even that argument only works if you already know the internationalization requirements well enough to decide on a satisfactory mechanism right now; that's not always the case.

P.S. In general, there's only a "correct way" to do something when *everyone's* needs are the same or very similar. It should go without saying that "displaying text to the user" is not the sort of thing where every program in the world has almost the same requirements.

Answer (score 0):

you can show values dynamically using js,

**HTML code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="test.js" ></script>
</head>
<body >
    <div id="Name">  
        <label> Click ME!!:</label><input id="Text" value="press" onclick="NameChanged()"  type="button"> 
    </div><br/>
    <label id="hello"></label>
</body>
</html>
```

**Js code:**

```
var welcome = "Welcome to my site !!!";

function NameChanged(){
  document.getElementById('hello').innerHTML = welcome;
}
```

here I have taken **welcome** as a variable to store desire value and created a label in Html to show that value in a particular position.

Comment: Note: the `<br>` tag does not use and does not need a closing slash in HTML and never has.